# Replace array like string to array with character replace

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, string, replace

I have a string like this `"12,a,{3,4},b,c"` , i need to convert it into an array in which the element in curly braces should be a sub array , the result should look like this

```
["12","a",[3,4],"b","c"]
```

For other eg:

`"12,a,b,c,{e,f}" --> ["12","a","b","c", ["e","f"]]`

`"{12,a},b,c,{c,d}" --> [["12","a"],"b","c", ["e","f"]]`

Comment: Would an array like this be acceptable? `[["12"],["a"],["3","4"],["b"],["c"]]` That could be expressed as a jagged array of Strings.

Comment: Yes should be but at last

Comment: What are you doing this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
a = "{12,a},b,c,{c,d}";
m = a.match(/{[^}]*}|[^,]+/g);
arr=[];

for (i=0; i<m.length; i++) {
    if (m[i].indexOf('{') >= 0)
        arr.push(m[i].replace(/[{}]/g, "").split(/,/));
    else
    arr.push(m[i]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[12,a],b,c,[c,d]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "12,a,{3,4},b,c,{2,3}";
var b = eval(("[" + a.replace(/{/g, '[').replace(/}/g, ']') + "]").replace(/[a-zA-Z]/g, function (all, match) { return "'" + all+ "'";}));
console.log(b)
```

Try this

Comment: b is string , i want b as an array

Comment: a = "12,'a',{3,4},'b','c',{2,3}"; is not possible its "12,a,{3,4},b,c,{2,3}"

Comment: @rab please explain why eval is bad idea?

Comment: @Sarath Saleem please check if you got the required answer

Answer (score 0):

could you try this .

```
var m = "{12,a},b,c,{c,d}".split(','),

result = m.reduce( function( a, b) {

    if ( b.indexOf('{') !== -1 || a.t.length ){
        a.t.push( b.replace(/\{|\}/,'') );
    } else {
        a.array.push( b );
    }

    if ( b.indexOf('}') !== -1 ){
        a.array.push( a.t );
        a.t = [];
    }
    return a ;

}, { array:[],t:[]} ).array;

console.log( result );
```